# How to sort a table column with select tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jquery plugin for sorting my tables. That plugin works very well with texts, numbers, dates and others. However it's not working when a column has "select" in "td" tag

```
   <tr>
    <td>1222</td>
    <td>Carlos Almeida</td> 
    <td>
        <select class="col-md-10" disable>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">AcessoUsuario</option>
            <option value="2">AcessoPropriedade</option>
            <option value="3">AcessoFuncionalidade</option>
        </select>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1212</td>
    <td>Jose Amaral</td> 
    <td>
        <select class="col-md-10" disable>
            <option value="1">AcessoUsuario</option>
            <option value="2"selected="selected">AcessoPropriedade</option>
            <option value="3">AcessoFuncionalidade</option>
        </select>   
  </tr>
```

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: would help if you identified the plugin you are using, perhaps it has an API method you can use

Comment: Hi Charlie...I'm using http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/

Comment: seems that the plugin only looks for text strings, likely better to switch to more robust sorting plugin that gives you access to elements